# short for custom surround with

Tags: eclipse

Is there any shortcut for surrounding any selection with a template from "Surround With..."?

In this special case, I defined a surround with brackets template... It would be a great enhancement to have such a shortcut.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The only shortcut I know about for surround templates
(that is for templates with **`${line_selection}`** variable in their definition)
has been introduced in eclipse 3.2 (refined actually in [eclipse3.2 M4](http://kano.net/write/eclipse-news-M4))

It is the "**Surround With Quick Fix**" mechanism

[image]
<sub>(source: [kano.net](http://kano.net/write/eclipse-news-M4_files/surround_with_template.png))</sub>

Assign a shortcut to Quick-Fix (CTRL-1 by default), and if your selection is eligible ((contains a line), all compliant templates will be displayed in the Quick-Fix dialog.

You will then be able to choose the appropriate surround template (like the one you defined).

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @VonC is not working on **Eclipse Kepler**. Use short cut for show surround with quick menu.

Select one or more lines in java editor press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> then you will get the popup context menu as shown below(Menu items differ based on the region of selection).

[image]